# Gradle and Spring Boot: create task for multipart project

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-boot

I have multipart project:

```
RootProject(build.gradle)
    part1
    part2
    webAdmin
    webApi
```

`webAdmin` and `webApi` uses Spring Boot and if I want to run `webAdmin` from `RootProject` folder I need to run command like that:

```
>: gradle :webAdmin:bootRun
```

I want create task in `build.gradle` file to run `gradle :webAdmin:bootRun` command like that:

```
>: gradle adminRun
```

How my task in `gradle` file should look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this config within main project `build.gradle`:

```
// in main project
task adminRun(dependsOn: ':webAdmin:bootRun') << {
    println 'admin run'
}
```

`dependsOn` makes `adminRun` dependant on your subproject task, while basically in this particular case it does nothing except post process `println 'admin run'`.

Comment: You can omit adding an action.

Comment: @Opal sure, it is only an info message and is not necessary.